# Select Data based on related data exist

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to select records based on related data exists.

```
var data = await _dbContext
.MyData
.Include(d => d.Related)
.Where(r => r.Related.Any())
.ToList();
```

The selection should only select data that has related data.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't this query work? It should be working. But I would put Include clause after the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = await _dbContext
                .MyData
                .Where(x => x.Related != null)
                .Include(d => d.Related)
                .ToList();
```

Without any constraints you will get left join
So if you used `[Required]` as attribute of RelatedId, you will get a left join

And study below mappings also

```
//for left joins        
modelBuilder.Entity<MyData>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.Related) 
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.RelatedId);

//for inner join
modelBuilder.Entity<MyData>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Related) 
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.RelatedId);
```